# email sending on button click without using intent

Tags: android

I want to send Email using button click. I found following code for use. But I am not able to send email using button click.
I am using code from http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/tag/send-email-via-smtp-in-android/
Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {   
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("werwerwerwer@gmail.com", "qwewrwewe");
                sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                        "This is Body",   
                        "werwewe@gmail.com",   
                        "werwerwer@gmail.com");   
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
            } 

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: So what is the problem? Any error occured??

Comment: no error occured..but i dont understand what happend i am doing it first time also i debug the code Session.getDefaulteIstance() methos return Javax.mail.session@43160... something like that and when putting breakpoint on send method the content of send methos containing errors

Comment: yes i solved problem i change mail.host int mail.smtp.host.Thank you for your valuable time.see you again ! :)

Comment: now i want to attch file into emiail from my sdcard ! if yo help that will be life saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Add the catch code for the try-catch in the method sendMail from GMailSender, put a breakpoint there and one at this line :

```
Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
```

in OnClick method in MainAvtivity.

Does it hit one of them?

Comment: i am debuging the code in Session.getDefaultInstance() it returns javax.mail.Session@405236e0 and Transport.send(message) method returnin all content null

Comment: Did you download the 3 jars from the first step from the link you got the code? Did you include them in your project?

Comment: yes i solved problem i change mail.host int mail.smtp.host.Thank you for your valuable time.see you again ! :)

Comment: now i want to attch file into emiail from my sdcard ! if yo help that will be life saver for me